# One-click deployment solution for my Node.js application (with pm2)

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, pm2, production

So basically, I have Node.js application locally (WebStorm project) and constantly pushing changes to git. I would like to create `one-click desployment` solution executable from my WebStorm project what will:

1. Clone/Pull project from git
2. Install dependencies
3. Edit config (database connection, etc...)
4. Based on config make sure database is ready and if not initialize new one

I achieved **parts 1 and 2** by using `pm2 deployment` function. If I run command, everything is updated from git and dependencies are installed.

**Part 3** is problem, because I do not want to push production config into git (even it is private repo) and I have only example config in git repo. I was thinking about script what will copy example config and then prompt me somehow to edit it, but I am not sure now to achieve this without connecting manually into production server and second problem is I need to copy new example config every new version, because there might be changes in config structure between versions.

Any suggestions how to achieve this easily and **without need to log into production server manually**?

**Part 4** is nice to have feature if anyone have suggestions how to achieve this, too.